# How to add new column in sales_order_grid.xml dynamically or direct from class?

Tags: sales-order, order-grid, magento2-3

[image]

I have created a configuration for selecting fields from sales_order table to join with sales_order_grid table. I need to show these selected extra fields on the sales order listing page. like the screenshot below.

[image]

When enabling the fields from configuration it will be shown in the order listing page. Could you please help me to sort out this issue.

I have tried below code in app/code/Vendor/OrderGrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xmlsales_order_grid.xml

```
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="customer_id" class="Venor\OrderGrid\Component\Fields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

And extend Column class by Fields Vendor\OrderGrid\Component\Fields.

```
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
               $item['componentDisabled'] = 1;
               $item['visible'] = 0;
            }
        }
    return $dataSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all columns in app/code/Vendor/OrderGrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

Then you need to control the column visibility dynamically.
To do that override the 'prepare' method on the Vendor\OrderGrid\Component\Fields.php like below

```
 public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();
        if ($this->canShowColumn()) {
            $this->_data['config']['componentDisabled'] = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks buddy

Comment: Check is there any caching issues also.